# Showing that intermediate field $D$ is contained in intermediate subfield $E$ given these conditions.

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $K/F$ is a Galois extension. Suppose $E$ and $D$ are intermediate fields of $K/F$. Let $p$ be a prime and assume that the following hold: (i) $[E:F]$ and $[D:F]$ are powers of $p$, (ii) $p$ does not divide $[K:E]$, and (iii) $K/D$ is Galois.

<strike>Show that $E$ is a subset of $D$.</strike> Show that $D$ is a subset of $E$.

I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours. Obviously, I need to use the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory somehow, but I can't figure out how. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: it was pointed out that there was a mistake. It should be $D$ is a subset of $E$.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your problem statement.  Let $[K:F]=p^nk$.  Then because $p \nmid [K:E]$ and $[K:F]=[K:E][E:F]$, we have $[E:F]=p^n$.  But if also $[D:F]$ is a power of $p$, then it's not possible for $E$ to be a subset of $D$ because $[D:F] \leq [E:F]$.

Comment: Hmm, I double-checked, and it says E is a subset of D. But your argument makes sense, and I think the author must have meant D is a subset of E. It's a qual question, so it's possible there was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to also change the title of the question to reflect the correction.